# Is there any option to filter my planner tasks using graph api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-planner

I want to filter my planner task using graph API for example by title.

Is it possible?

```
.api('/me/planner/tasks')
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph [List tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0) does not support any query parameters like `$filter` at this moment.

So, you have fetch all your tasks and then apply filter at the client side.